# What is wrong with this python game?

Tags: python, text, global-variables

A friend of mine has been making a text based game in python.The game seems to be going well so far, but we keep getting an error saying "if  gamemap == [0,0]:
NameError: global name 'gamemap' is not defined".Thank you so much for your help.

Here is the code.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1m0Ue7SDg5kZCSYGS7XqqGEH_J4RNtX_kwhPD9gKizxc/edit

Comment: Also, it'd help to copy and paste the complete stack trace of the error into your question. **Never retype code or errors into your question when you can copy/paste from original source code or actual program output.** I suspect your error was actually an uninitialized *local* variable, not global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to declare the gamemap variable *global* before you call it in each of your functions:

```
def func():
    global gamemap
    # rest of your code goes here
```